# Did my compiler ignore my unused static thread_local class member?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, thread-local-storage

I want do some thread registration in my class, so I decide to add a check for the the `thread_local` feature:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() {
    std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl;
  }
  ~Foo() {
    std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Bar {
 public:
  Bar() {
    std::cout << "Bar()" << std::endl;
    //foo;
  }
  ~Bar() {
    std::cout << "~Bar()" << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  static thread_local Foo foo;
};

thread_local Foo Bar::foo;

void worker() {
  {
    std::cout << "enter block" << std::endl;
    Bar bar1;
    Bar bar2;
    std::cout << "exit block" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread t1(worker);
  std::thread t2(worker);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  std::cout << "thread died" << std::endl;
}
```

The code is simple.  My `Bar` class has a static `thread_local` member `foo`. If a static `thread_local` `Foo foo` is created, it means a thread is created.

But when I run the code, nothing in the `Foo()` prints, and if I remove the comment in `Bar`'s constructor, which uses `foo`, the code works fine.

I tried this on GCC (7.4.0) and Clang (6.0.0) and the results are the same.
I guess that the compiler discovered that `foo` is unused and do not generate an instance. So

1. Did the compiler ignore the `static thread_local` member? How can I
   debug for this?
2. If so, why does a normal `static` member not have this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem with your observation.  [[basic.stc.static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.static#2) prohibits eliminating variables with static storage duration:

> If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a
>   destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated even if it
>   appears to be unused, except that a class object or its copy/move may
>   be eliminated as specified in [class.copy].

This restriction is not present for other storage durations.  In fact, [[basic.stc.thread]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.thread#2) says:

> A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized before
>   its first odr-use and, **if constructed**, shall be destroyed on
>   thread exit.

This suggests that a variable with thread storage duration need not be constructed unless odr-used.

---

But why is this discrepancy?

For static storage duration, there is only one instance of a variable per program.  The side effects of construction thereof can be significant (kinda like a program-wide constructor), so the side effects are required.

For thread local storage duration, however, there is a problem: an algorithm may start a lot of threads.  For most of these threads, the variable is completely irrelevant.  It would be hilarious if an external physics simulation library that calls `std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, first, last)` ends up creating a lot of `foo` instances, right?

Of course, there can be a legitimate use for side effects of the construction of variables of thread local storage duration that are not odr-used (e.g., a thread tracker).  However, the advantage for *guaranteeing* this is not enough to compensate for the aforementioned drawback, so these variables are allowed to be eliminated as long as they aren't odr-used.  (Your compiler can choose not to do, though.  And you can also make your own wrapper around `std::thread` that takes care of this.)

Comment: Okay...if the standard said so, than so be it... But isn't it weird the committee do not consider the side effects as static storage duration?

Answer (score 1):

I found this information in "[ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf)" which can prove @L.F. 's answer

> In addition the run-time support should avoid creating the
>   thread-local storage if it is not necessary. For instance, a loaded
>   module might only be used by one thread of the many which make up the
>   process. It would be a waste of memory and time to allocate the
>   storage for all threads. A lazy method is wanted. This is not much
>   extra burden since the requirement to handle dynamically loaded
>   objects already requires recognizing storage which is not yet
>   allocated. This is the only alternative to stopping all threads and
>   allocating storage for all threads before letting them run again.